# MySQL query to get the top 50 names appearing the most in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL table is simple:

```
id | name | create_time
```

Every time the user makes an operation, it inserts one record into this table, like

```
1 | "do ABC" | 2011-12-05

2 | "do BCD" | 2011-12-05
```

I want to get the top 50 operations from this table during the last 7 days. How can I write the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(id), name
from tablename
where DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) < create_time 
group by name
order by count(id) desc
limit 50;
```

Comment: If the table size became big, would this SQL query be slow?

Comment: Potentially.  But that's true of any query.  If it became an issue you could look at adding an index on the name & create_time columns, but you'd have to trade that off against the additional cost of insert.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(id) as operations
FROM myTable
WHERE create_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY `name` 
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

This will count the number of operations for each operation name, sort the results by the count and only return 50 records. Please note that this is exactly seven days of history, in other words if you run the query at noon, the beginning of the range will be noon 7 days ago.

See [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm), [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: This has a syntax error, it needs to be `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval -7 DAY) AND NOW()` and seeing as it's negative you're better off using `date_sub`

Comment: Thank you M_M, but Glenn's looks better.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `create_time` >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get result by this query

```
select id, name, create_time
from tablename
where DATEDIFF(dd,create_time ,NOW())=7
order by create_time
limit 50;
```